# The coarea formula question in analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let assume $f\in C_c^\infty(R^N)$, as good as we want.

Let's define 
$$m(t):=\int_{\{f\leq t\}}|Df|dx.$$

I am wondering that is it make sense to talk about the derivative of $m(t)$? For example, can I expect
$$m'(t)=\int_{\partial\{f\leq t\}}|Df|d\mathcal{H}^{N-1}?$$
Moreover, is it possible to obtain
$$\int_{\partial\{f\leq t\}}|Df|d\mathcal{H}^{N-1} = \mathcal{H}^{N-1}(\{f=t\})?$$
Or something like this?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you actually have that $\int\limits_{\partial \{f=t\}} d H^{N-1}=H^{N-1}(\{f=t\})$. The $|Df|$ is absorbed to give $ df $ when going from one side of the coarea formula to the other.

Second you know that $ m'(t) $ will exist for almost every $ t $ because $ m (t) $ is a non decreasing function. Also $$ m'(t)=H^{N-1}(\{f=t\}). $$

Yes the coarea will even work for lipschitz functions. Just check any book on geometric measure theory such as Krantz and Parks "Geometric Integration Theory".

Comment: So, it looks to me, that when I do derivative w.r.to t, I am actually differentiate the domain? Of course I will go check the book you mentioned. Thx!

Comment: Yes, the domain is changing, but it's at a rate of volume determined by $|Df|^{-1}$. The coarea formula gives 

$$ \int\limits_{\{f\leq t\}} |Df|d H^N = \int\limits_{s = -\infty}^t \left(\int\limits_{\{f=s\}} dH^{N-1}\right)dt.$$

The integral on the right has "simplified" the changing of the domain into a 1D integral which is straightforward to differentiate.